# Why would a non-Christian religion suddenly gain a large following among Americans?

Tags: society, culture, religion, united-states

Eighty years into the future, an already existing non-Christian religion has gained a widespread following among Americans. Millions of people have converted to the religion in question.

From what I have researched, the largest non-Christian universalizing religions in the United States are Mormonism, Islam, and Buddhism.

Why would this happen? In addition, what pre-existing religion is most likely to take on this role?

Comment: Mormonism is a side branch of Christianity (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Mormonism).

Comment: VTC: hard to see how answer to such question can be spoon in non-opinion, non-story writing, non-fantasy generating way.

Comment: I think picking an existing religion could be potentially alienating to your audience.   Do you want to do this major conversion of the populace without major bloodshed?

Comment: Look back in history as to how religions spread. In most cases, to gain substantial following in a population, the religion was supported by the government and membership became important to economic advancement. In many cases, membership became important to continued living. So, force and economics were behind the spread. So, you need to define how those pressures could exist in the US. In the past, those pressures existed in small towns which is why those towns have a dominant religion.

Comment: Hi Galactic. This got closed because "why would [someone] do this?" is always story-based. Remember, worldbuilding (on-topic) is about creating and consistently using the rules and systems that define a fictional world of your own creation wherein an infinite number of stories can be told. Storybuilding (off-topic) is about plot, circumstances, and character actions and decisions. "Character" can be one person or an entire species.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Islam has the advantage in this, I think, because it includes the most of the others.

[Mormonism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mormons) is, as others have indicated, a branch of Christianity.

Islam accepts [Jesus Christ as a Moses' promised "prophet greater than me" (the Messiah)](https://quran.com/4/171), [accepts his resurrection](https://quran.com/4/157) (or it could be interpreted that way, but many don't), and includes that [Jesus will return](https://discoveringislam.org/return_of_jesus.htm) at the end of days.

Islam also accepts the people of the book (Judaism), and acknowledges both the Book and the words of Christ as true and god-inspired.

Muhammed's own contributions to the word echo the words of Jesus "love your enemies", Moses "serve only god (subnission == "islam"), Isaiah "god wants obedience more than sacrifice".

What's holding Islam back is, in my opinion, what Paul in his letter's "people who preach a gospel different from the one we taught you", or what John calls "people adding or subtracting" to the frustratingly simple message: obey god, which will reveal itself in your life by how much you give to others compared to what you take from them.

Also holding back Islam is the popular interpretation of the Sura cited that "Jesus was crucified, but didn't really die". It COULD be interpreted the way christians do : that Jesus was crucified and resurrected by God. This is important to Christians because, if a good human being was really raised from the dead, you have evidence (not just mere hope) that God CAN do such a thing and that God's promises not seemingly filled in our lifetimes (Abraham died with only a single son to his name, not nations), those promises will ALL BE KEPT eventually, and we will be resurrected on day to enjoy these kept promises. The popular interpretation of Islam to the above passage is that someone else (still by miraculous act of shape-shifting) took Jesus' place on the cross). Which would leave all the rest of the hope as still only hope...

Ignorance is also holding Islam back. The press is still fighting the crusades. Literally, that's what gets brought up in any conversation lasting longer than 30 minutes. On both sides. As a species, we need to move past letting some small group of ignorants do our thinking for us.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible (if it could it would already happen) for any already existing religion unless a true prophet/saint capable of performing true miracles appear. However, if such a figure appears it would be hard to say whether it is one of the old religions or a new one.

Check the history of [Abrahamic religions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Abrahamic_religions) (Judaism, Christianity, and Islam are the best-known ones). Jesus and Muhammad are the main figures (also can be seen as 'founders') in Christianity and Islam correspondingly. They were seen as false prophets or madmen by their contemporaries belonging to already established religions, despite the fact that both Christianity and Islam respect previous traditions, sacred texts, and even major figures (prophets, saints, mythological creatures).

There is a remote possibility that a prominent political and religious figure appears and somehow manages to start the unification of the entire world (the world, because the USA is already more or less united). If this happens, most likely, the religion they will promote will be based on Abrahamic tradition, since it has the greatest number of adherents in the world ([over 50% of the total world population worship the God of Abraham](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_religious_populations)). I think this is the most realistic scenario if you absolutely need millions of Americans to convert into a new religion without any divine intervention.

Answer (score 1):

Religions fulfill the task of providing answers to the big questions everybody has on life (side note: in case they don't know yet that the answer is 42).

As long as a system of beliefs satisfies that, no matter it is Christian or non-Christian, it will attract followers.

Incidentally, that's also how sects grow and expand: they offer an environment where adepts can sooth their uneasiness with life.

Additionally, it helps religious expansion if the religion is paired with/supported by an expanding political power which is conquering new territories and informing the local population with their values and creeds.